# How to separate jQuery hide/show button from the hidden/shown div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, slidetoggle

I would like to use a clickable div in my header to reveal a div surposedly below my main content area, but I can't figure out how to do that. Right now I'm using a basic jQuery like this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    jQuery(".expand").click(function()
    {
    jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

and a html like this:

```
<div class="expand">expand</div>
<div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
```

but if I separate the two divs, the function breaks.

If you can lead me in the right direction, it will me much appreciated!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

> *but if I separate the two divs, the function breaks.*

Because you're using `next()` which gets the next element next to `$(this)`. This will work no matter where `.content` is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var $content = jQuery(".content"); // Cache
    $content.hide();
    jQuery(".expand").click(function () {
        $content.slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `nextAll().first()` instead of `next()`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    jQuery(".expand").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).nextAll(".content").first().slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

This way if you have multiple `.content` on your page, `.expand` will only expand the next `.content` on the page.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you can do here to improve performance and stability. First off, instead of using the `next()` method, you would just use

```
$('.expand').click(function () { $('.content').slideToggle(500); });
```

Of course, this has the obvious drawback (?) of expanding and contracting *all* `.content` areas when you click on *any* `.expand`.

But, you can improve your performance and stability if you add a couple of html attributes to the `.expand` and the `.content`, like so:

```
<div class="expand" data-for="content_id">Click to toggle</div>
<div class="content" id="content_id">This is the toggable content</div>
```

First, this requires a recent version of jQuery (ideally 1.6 or greater) for the `data-` attributes. I use a `data-for` to signify that one particular `.expand` applies to one particular `.content`. This is similar to using the `for` attribute on `label` and form elements.

Second, the `.content` areas have a new (and unique to each one) `id` applied. This lets jQuery selectors target those items much quicker through the `getElementById()` function.

Finally, the new javascript would look like this:

```
$('.expand').click(function () {
    var id = '#' + $(this).data('for');
    $(id).slideToggle(500); 
});
```

And if you need accordian functionality (ie, roll up all `.content` whenever one is clicked, and activate the item that matches the clicked `data-for`:

```
$('.expand').click(function () {
    var id = '#' + $(this).data('for');

    $('.content').slideUp(500);
    $(id).slideDown(500); 
});
```